# Create DocumentSet with REST api

Tags: rest, sharepoint, document-set

How would one format the rest uri to create a document set in SP?

The JSOM code below works fine, but I would prefer to use the REST in order to be able to call it from a workflow.

```
var dsresult = SP.DocumentSet.DocumentSet.create(context, parentFolder, "docsetfromjsom", docsetCtId);
```

I tried this format based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292556(v=office.15).aspx) MSDN article

```
var restQueryUrl = spAppWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/SP.DocumentSet.DocumentSet.create('serverrelativeurl','docsetname','ctid')?@target='spHostUrl'";
```

Tried other formats as well but none successful. In jsom you also need to include the context, but I am assuming that for the rest call you don't need to use it (i think). Anyone tried this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've [already answered](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/117460/10610) a [similar question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/114882/10610) at [SharePoint StackExchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/).

To summarize, it does not seem possible to create Document Set using SharePoint 2013 REST API since `SP.DocumentSet.DocumentSet.create` function is not accessible via REST. But you could utilize SharePoint 2010 REST API instead for that purpose.

The following example demonstrates how to create a Document Set using SharePoint 2010 REST Interface:

```
function getListUrl(webUrl,listName) 
{
    return $.ajax({       
       url: webUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/rootFolder?$select=ServerRelativeUrl",   
       type: "GET",   
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: { 
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
       }
    });
}


function createFolder(webUrl,listName,folderUrl,folderContentTypeId) 
{                
     return $.ajax({
           url: webUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listName,
           type: "POST",
           contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
           headers: {
              "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
              "Slug": folderUrl + "|" + folderContentTypeId
           }
     });
}


function createDocumentSet(webUrl,listName,docSetName)
{
    return getListUrl(webUrl,listName)
           .then(function(data){
               var folderUrl = data.d.ServerRelativeUrl + '/' + docSetName;
               return createFolder(webUrl,listName,folderUrl,'0x0120D520');
           }); 
}
```

**Usage**

Create Document Set named `Orders` in Documents library:

```
createDocumentSet(webUrl,'Documents','Orders')
.done(function(data)
{
    console.log('Document Set ' + data.d.Name + ' has been created succesfully'); 
})
.fail(
function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```